# How to customize in axis while plotting in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a graph from csv file.
however in the output graph x is ranging between 1 to 6 and it is represented like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.
What changes i should made in code so that it will be represented in `[1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6]`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as px
df = pd.read_csv('/home/madhu/Desktop/plotDatap4.csv')
df.plot(kind='line',x='Access Distance(in log)',y='Cummulative probability')
px.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to add `xticks`? Can you share your data and plot.

Comment: I have added the image . please check

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.plot(df.x, df.y)
plt.xticks([1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xticks` function on plot to solve it.
This code will automatically read your column vales with `head()` function, and divide it into `step` value you want to use.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as px

step = 0.5
column = 'Access Distance(in log)'

df = pd.read_csv('/home/madhu/Desktop/plotDatap4.csv')
df.plot(kind='line',x='a',y='b')
px.xticks(np.arange(min(df.head()[column].tolist()),max(df.head()[column].tolist()),step))
px.show()
```

I hope this helped.